# Double Pointer Using Error

Tags: c

I am having a trouble while practicing double pointer
The Error is "EXE_BAD_ACCESS" in Xcode

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Program to Get Min and Max Value 
         in Array */

void SaveValue(int **maxPtr, int **minPtr, int arr[])
{
    int i;  
**maxPtr=arr[0];          // Error Line
**minPtr=arr[0];          // Error Line

    for(i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>**maxPtr)
            **maxPtr=arr[i];
        else if(arr[i]<**minPtr)
            **minPtr=arr[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5]={4, 5, 7, 2, 6};
    int *maxptr;
    int *minptr;

    SaveValue(&maxptr, &minptr, arr);

    printf("%d, %d \n", *maxptr, *minptr);
}
```

I've thought that `*dptr` of `**dptr = &ptr` is `*ptr`

and `**dptr` means variable which `*ptr` pointing.

so I assume that `**dptr = arr[0]` means save first num of `arr` by reference at variable which `*ptr` pointing!

but I experiencing access error now.. I will thank for your help!

Comment: `*maxPtr` is a pointer; where is it pointing to?

Comment: You do not need double pointers here.

Comment: @interjay: of course it does, it's just not being used correctly.  `maxPtr` and `minPtr` are being used as output parameters.

Comment: I do not see double pointer here!

Comment: @JeffMercado If the function is supposed to "Get Min and Max Value" as the comment says, then `int*` is enough. If it's supposed to get a *pointer* to the min/max values, then alk's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void SaveValue(int **maxPtr, int **minPtr, int arr[]);` provides pointers to pointers to `int` so use them as such.

```
void SaveValue(int **maxPtr, int **minPtr, int arr[])
{
  int i;  
  *maxPtr=arr + 0; /* same as *maxPtr = &arr[0]; */
  *minPtr=arr + 0; /* same as *maxPtr = &arr[0]; */

  for(i = 1; i < 5; i++)
  {
    if(arr[i] > **maxPtr)
        *maxPtr = arr + i; /* same as *maxPtr = &arr[i]; */
      else if(arr[i] < **minPtr)
        *minPtr = arr + i; /* same as *minPtr = &arr[i]; */
  }
}
```

Also this interface is a bit dangerous and unflexible; so why not pass the size of the array as well:

```
void SaveValue(int **maxPtr, int **minPtr, int arr[], ssize_t s)
{
  *maxPtr=arr + 0; 
  *minPtr=arr + 0; 

  for(--s; s >= 0; --s)
  {
    if(arr[s] > **maxPtr)
    {
      *maxPtr = arr + s; 
    }
    else if(arr[i] < **minPtr)
    {
      *minPtr = arr + s; 
    }
  }
}
```

Call the fcuntion like this:

```
  SaveValue(&maxptr, &minptr, arr, sizeof arr/sizeof *arr);
```

As the return value of the function is unused we could utlize it to apply some error inidication to allow the user of the function to write more stable code:

```
int SaveValue(int ** maxPtr, int ** minPtr, int arr[], ssize_t s)
{
  int result = 0;

  if ((NULL == arr) || (NULL == maxPtr) || (NULL == minPtr) || (0 > s))
  {
    result = -1;
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    *maxPtr=arr + 0; 
    *minPtr=arr + 0; 

    for(--s; s >= 0; --s)
    {
      if(arr[s] > **maxPtr)
      {
        *maxPtr = arr + s; 
      }
      else if(arr[i] < **minPtr)
      {
        *minPtr = arr + s; 
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int SaveValue(int ** maxPtr, int ** minPtr, int arr[], ssize_t s);

int main(void)
{
  int arr[5]={4, 5, 7, 2, 6};
  int *maxPtr;
  int *minPtr;

  int result = SaveValue(&maxPtr, &minPtr, arr, sizeof arr/sizeof *arr);

  if (-1 == result)
  {
    perror("SaveValue() failed")
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%d, %d \n", *maxPtr, *minPtr);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what was intended, output parameters. Almost the only reason why you would want double pointers around that isn't holding on to dynamically allocated memory. I'd also suggest giving the variables better names to further drive home what the intended uses are.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer should be pointing to valid memory location before dereferencing it else it will lead to undefined behavior. Below changes will fix your error.

```
int max;
int min;

int *maxptr = &max;
int *minptr = &min;
```

There is no need of double pointer here change your function prototype to

```
void SaveValue(int *maxPtr, int *minPtr, int arr[])
```

Have

```
int max;
int min;
```

in `main()` and call this API accordingly

```
SaveValue(&max,&min,arr);
```

Comment: Why so complicated? A simple `int max; int * maxptr = &max`  would do (same minimum).

Comment: @alk Completely agree but just went with what OP had the cause for the crash was `pointer was not pointing to valid memory location`

Comment: I know, and my approach let's the pointer point to valid memory without *explicit dynamic* allocation.

Comment: @alk Yes your approach is ok but wanted to let know OP what was his mistake

Comment: Your initial solutions proposed the use of `malloc()` to initialise the two pointers. Which I didn't judged wrong, but just sort of over-designed ... ;-)

Comment: @alk oh ok.. removed it .. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your code is purely for pointer learning purposes and not an attempt to implement this operation in a practical situation. So if you want to have `maxptr` and `minptr` in `main()` pointing to the maximum and minimum values in `arr[]`, I think you should change your double pointer assignments from `**maxPtr=arr[0]` to `*maxPtr=&arr[0]`, so your code would become:

```
void SaveValue(int **maxPtr, int **minPtr, int arr[])
{
    int i;
    *maxPtr = &arr[0];      // Error Line
    *minPtr = &arr[0];      // Error Line

    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > **maxPtr)
            *maxPtr = &arr[i];
        else if (arr[i] < **minPtr)
            *minPtr = &arr[i];
    }
}
```

In this case, when you make the assignments, you don't want to dereference the double pointers. Instead, you should assign it with the address of the element you want to show when you dereference them in main().

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use the double asterisk when initialize the maxPtr and minPtr pointers in the function SaveValue, neither in the for loop body. MaxPtr and minPtr both are double pointers, but is still the memory direction of maxptr in main(). So you only need to dereference them with a single asterisk, to acces the memory direction them points to.
The source correct source code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Correct program to Get Min and Max Value in Array */

void SaveValue(int **maxPtr, int **minPtr, int arr[])
{
    int i;  
    *maxPtr=arr[0];       
    *minPtr=arr[0];   
    for(i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>*maxPtr)
            *maxPtr=arr[i];
        else if(arr[i]<*minPtr)
            *minPtr=arr[i];
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5]={4, 5, 7, 2, 6};
    int *maxptr;
    int *minptr;

    SaveValue(&maxptr, &minptr, arr);

    printf("%d, %d \n", maxptr, minptr);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with GCC and execute it, i get the next output:
7, 2.
Remember that depending of the environment (Operating System, version, compiler, standards) that you use  the program results may vary.

Comment: You might like to compile with all warnings on, to learn your proposal does not compile well. `*maxPtr` is a pointer to `int`, not an `int`. Doing `*maxPtr = arr[0]` simply is wrong. It provokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: "*Remember that depending of the environment (Operating System, version, compiler, standards) that you use the program results may vary.*" It won't if code correctly.